# Sumif (google sheets) but data is every nth cell in a column, every nth column based on cell n-4

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, lambda, sum, google-sheets-formula

Im trying to make a budget tracker
[image]

Is there a way i can sum every nth cell in a column if the n-4 is a specific string?

I found [this](https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/how-to-sum-every-nth-row-in-google-sheets/) but not sure how i can add a "=person A" to the criteria.

Is there a better way to format this data  ?

Comment: Kindly add input table and expected output table as **text table** (NOT as IMAGE) to the question. [Click here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to create a table easily. Adding such tables greatly increases your chances of getting a elegant answer, as **it is easier to copy/paste**. If you share spreadsheets, your question maybe closed, as questions here must be [self contained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), if you share Google files.

Comment: it is not clear what kind of SUM you require... row-wise, column-wise or whole dataset-wise

Comment: @player0 I want on each date (columns) do a sum and calculate the spending of each person in a different cell, so in yellow rows I can write how much each person has spent that day

Comment: @TheMaster thanks so much, I have added the photo and removed the link

Comment: answer updated..

Comment: @AminGharavi My comment specifically asks you not to post a image in big capital letters.  Furthermore, Even with the photo, it's still unclear what the expected output is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try in C2 and drag to the right:

```
=INDEX(BYROW(REGEXREPLACE($A2:$A3, "(?i)total ", ), 
 LAMBDA(T, SUM(IFNA(FILTER(C7:C15, C4:C12=T))))))
```

[image]

⠀‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀ ⠀‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀

Comment: It works as it intended thank you so much and I understand it a little bit.